# How draw dotted circle using google maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps

How draw dotted circle using google maps api? I mean stylize default circle that we draw using method map.addCirlce().

Like this:[dotted circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQPVV.png)

Comment: oh, sorry my friend. i used wrong tag.. it's not about js, i mean android api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

plz, use official google docs
[Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle)

you need Stroke Pattern

```
 java.util.List<PatternItem> pattern = Arrays.<PatternItem>asList(new Dot());
    map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .radius(radius)
            .strokePattern(pattern)
```