# How to draw a dotted Polygon and Circle using "@react-google-maps/api"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am using `@react-google-maps/api": "1.8.2"` and wanted to draw a dotted polygon and circleBut when I pass options `({icons: [icon: lineSymbol, repeat: '10px]})` to the  or .  its not working.

```
const lineSymbol = {
    path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
    scale: 2,
    strokeColor: 'green',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
}
const polygonProps = {
        options: {
            fillOpacity: 0,
            icons: [{
                icon: lineSymbol,
                offset: '0',
                repeat: '10px',
            }, ],
            // strokeColor: polygonData.strokeColor,
            // strokeWidth: 1,
            zIndex: polygonData.zIndex || 10,
        },
        path: polygonData.pointList.map(item => ({
            lat: item[0],
            lng: item[1]
        })),
        title: polygonData.title,
    }

    <
    Polygon {
        ...polygonProps
    }
/>
```

> here I found similar task on google map [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982732/how-draw-dotted-circle-using-google-maps-api)

Comment: did I answer your question sufficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customise the stroke of Polygons and Circles like you can with Polylines.

We customise Polylines with the following syntax:

```js
// Define a symbol using SVG path notation, with an opacity of 1.
const lineSymbol = {
  path: "M 0,-1 0,1",
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  scale: 4
};
```

From the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols):

*Symbols are useful when you want to use a vector-based icon on a marker, or add an image to a **polyline***

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-question-5t73h?file=/src/App.js) showing how to customise polylines.

Your only option (this won't work with Circles, only Polygons) is to render your Polygons as Polylines, which you can then style. Personally I would not bother.

Sorry I don't have better news for you!